# Why is my textfield's text not changed in the callback for UIControlEventEditingDidEnd?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I'm using [UIDownPicker](https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker) in my app and I'm trying to register for its UIControlEvents. It's basically a UITextField so I use this

```
UIDownPicker *pick = [[UIDownPicker alloc] initWithData:myData];
[pick addTarget:self action:@selector(onDownPickerEditDidEnd:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

to initialise the downPicker and add the callback target. I implemented the following in the same class:

```
- (void) onDownPickerEditDidEnd:(id)downPicker forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)event);
    NSLog(@"%@", downPicker);
}
```

When I read the text from the downPicker it is still the old text (from before the user selected something else). The downPicker parameter always contains the downPicker that was changed, but the event parameter is always nil.

There's clearly something off, but I can't figure out what. Using a normal UITextField this would definitely work and I've used UIDownPicker like this before without problems. What could be wrong that causes the event to fire at the right moment, but with old data? I can't think of anything.

Comment: have you set it's delegate?

Comment: @SanketBhavsar I'm using the addTarget way, I never set a delegate when using addTarget, is that a necessity?

Comment: @SanketBhavsar I tried setting the delegate, it breaks the entire UIDownPicker.

Comment: ok..let me check something else

Comment: my demo is working fine...